# Can kubernetes manage hardware devices?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am looking at ways to shift from our monolith system to more flexible microservice based, and from managing the application(containerized) standpoint, Kubernetes comes as the frontrunner.

In our ecosystem, there are some hardware devices that are to be a part as it is. Understanding Kubernetes (in the limited time) do not provide me a clear-cut way if managing the HW is a possibility with Kubernetes or not. I explored CRDs, Addons etc., but those approaches did not look promising to my use case of managing HW nodes.

My use case for managing HW nodes include: 
1. Discovery of HW devices by K8s
2. Possibly managing them over REST API through K8s. 
* High availability of HW devices is not in scope, however, any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Hi, Can I know what are these "Hardware"(HW) node?...Not sure what you are saying, K8s manages/orchestrate docker container,,,You want K8s to manage hardware(HW) node?

Comment: yes HW devices management

Comment: The Kubernetes isn't built for it. Discovering any HW is not Kubernetes task

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes was developed as an automation deployment, orchestration and management tool for containerised applications. However, its role does not involve managing and discovering Hardware nodes, because Kubernetes implements own internal structure components by populating services across the Nodes in the cluster.

You can consider launching support for various compute, storage, etc. devices that require specific setup in Kubernetes cluster within [Device plugin framework](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/resource-management/device-plugin.md).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and suggestion.